# Using urls in Django 1.9

Tags: django, django-1.9

I'm using Django 1.9.7 with Python 3.5.1

I'm rather new to Django, building a simple application. I currently have an issue with URLs.

I would like to have the following behaviour:
if user gets to http:.../entry/2016/03 he sees data for March 2016
but if user gets t: http:.../entry then rather than getting a 404, he should be redirected to http:.../entry/2016/06 (assuming we're in June 2016).

Currently, here's how I did it:

```
url(r'^entry/$', Entry.as_view(), name='entry0'),
url(r'^entry/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{1,2})/$', Entry.as_view(), name='entry'),
```

and the view is defined as:

```
def get(self, request, year=datetime.datetime.year, month=datetime.datetime.month):
```

in the template, I have:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'entry' year month%}">Entry</a></li>
```

The issue is that when I go to /entry, I get the following error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /entry/

Reverse for 'entry' with arguments '(<attribute 'year' of 'datetime.date' objects>, <attribute 'month' of 'datetime.date' objects>)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['entry/(?P<year>\\d{4})/(?P<month>\\d{1,2})/$']
```

However, getting to /entry/2016/06 works properly.

What would be the cleanest way to get this working? Can I achieve this with a single url and view?

Best regards

Jean-Noël

#

As suggested, I modified a bit the view:

```
def get(self, request, year=None, month=None):
    if year is None:
        year = datetime.datetime.today().year
    if month is None:
        month = datetime.datetime.today().month        
    context = {'current_date': datetime.datetime.now(),
               'year': year,
               'month': month,
               }
```

the urls remain the same:

```
url(r'^entry/$', Entry.as_view(), name='entry0'),
url(r'^entry/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{1,2})/$', Entry.as_view(), name='entry'),
```

the template only points to the empty url:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'entry0' %}">Entry</a></li>
```

This seems to work; when clicking on the link in the template, I'm sent to the default values; but if I specify a value in the url, I'm sent to the right values.

My last question is: can't I do that in one single view and url? Basically, when using /entry, the parameters would be set to None, while when specifying them, they're received in the view.

THanks a lot

Jean-Noël

Comment: Your variables in the template have strange values, how do you set them?

Answer (score 1):

You're passing attributes that do not have any value as your defaults. You should do this instead:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

def get(self, request, year=None, month=None):
    if year is None:
        year = dt.today().year
    if month is None:
        month = dt.today().month
```

To use this in your template:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'entry0' %}">Entry</a></li>
```

Comment: But if that error is coming from his template, then this isn't even the mistake.  Apparently his year and month variables in the template are *also* those methods from datetime.datetime.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich he already has a named url `entry0`, he needs to use that instead.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich The original problem is that the OP was incorrectly using `datetime.datetime.year` and `datetime.datetime.month` as defaults, which are then passed to the template by the view. Once the `get()` method has been fixed as Moses suggests, it will be ok to use `{% url 'entry' year month %}`.

Comment: @Alasdair: ah right, that's an explanation that makes sense, the view passes on the values to the template. I thought it might have been two separate bugs. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Your url template tag should get keyword args instead of just args

```
<li><a href="{% url 'entry' year=year month=month%}">Entry</a></li>
```

Comment: This won't fix the problem, it is ok to pass args to the url tag.

Answer (score 0):

OK, first things first. The whole logic of yours isn't clean or pythonic.
You need 1 url, 1 view and 1 template

```
url(r'^entry/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{1,2})/$', Entry.as_view(),name='entry')
```

define your view

```
def get(self, request, year=None, month=None):
```

Now, inside your view check if your params have value None,

```
if (year is None) and (month is None) :
# set today values
```

mplah mplah mplah.....
hope you get the point....

Comment: Yes, I did check that section, but it's using multiple urls, while I'd like to use only one, and defer to the view the check whether or not the parameters have been provided.